# If $I[x]$ is a radical ideal of $R[x]$, then show that $I$ is a radical ideal of $R.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, radicals

Show that $I$ is a radical ideal of a commutative ring $R$ iff $I[x]$ is a radical ideal of $R[x].$

The problem is in the ''only if'' part.If $I[x]$ is a radical ideal of $R[x],$ then $I[x] = \sqrt J$ for some ideal $J$ of $R[x].$

Then, how to find an ideal of $R$ whose radix will be $I?$
Will such an ideal be unique?

Comment: What is $R$ here?

Comment: Here, $R$ is a ring , not necessarily the set of all reals .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $I \subset R$ is radical if and only if the quotient ring $R/I$ is reduced (has no non-trivial nilpotents). Your statement is now immediate since $R/I \cong R[x]/I[x].$